# Placeholders not working in prepared statement

Tags: pdo

I have a working query, however when I try to replace variables with placeholders using prepared statements, something breaks. What am I missing here?

```
$sql = "
    SELECT t1.tbl, 
           COALESCE(t2.title, tx_ctr.Name) AS title
    FROM aux
    LEFT JOIN tx_chs
      ON t1.tbl = 't2' AND t1.rid = t2.cid  AND t2.county = :county
    LEFT JOIN tx_ctr
      ON t1.tbl = 't3' AND t1.rid = t3.id  AND t3.county = :county
    WHERE t1.tag LIKE :tag
      AND COALESCE(t2.cid, t3.ttl) IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY title ASC";

$qtag = '"%'.$tag.'%"';

$stmt  = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(['county' => $cnty, 'tag' => $qtag]);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: A possible reason can be the fact, that you are using one paremeter multiple times. Try to change the statement and use `:county1` and `:county2` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the ":" for your named parameters

Your executue statement has to look like this:

```
$stmt->execute([':county' => $cnty, ':tag' => $qtag]);
```